# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'TextArea'

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the model I have. I'm trying to make notes a textarea and when I try to makemigrations I get the `module 'django.db.models has no attribute TextArea'`

```js
class Note(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    notes = models.TextArea()
```

Not sure if i should use django.forms model on this, if so should i have two models, one for Note and another for NoteForms to handle the textarea field.

Comment: As the error says, there is no such model field as `TextArea`. You probably want [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) instead .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store variable length of text you can use

`a = models.TextField()`.

Model Have no attribute TextArea(). If you know the maximum length of text that can be entered using text area then you can use CharField.

```
a = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiline text then you can use [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField):

```
notes = models.TextField()
```